# Почему refresh token должен жить дольше, чем access?

Tags: auth, jwt, token, authenticationtoken

Почив про JWT я узнал, что access токен многоразовый, но короткоживущий. Используется для получения доступа к ресурсам. Сервер проверяет этот токен и в соответствии с результатом либо позволяет нам получить доступ, либо нет.

Refresh токен же наоборот, одноразовый, но долгоживущий. Используется для получения новой пары access + refresh в тот момент, когда access протухает.

Соответственно вопрос вот какой: в чём смысл делать refresh токен долгоживущим, если по факту он будет жить столько, сколько живёт access? Моё предположение, что это сделано для того, чтобы спустя условно 10 дней пользователь также мог воспользоваться refresh токеном и получить новую пару refresh + access. Тогда созревает другое вопрос, а получение этой новый пары не собьёт аутентификацию? Не придётся ли пользователю вновь логиниться в приложении?

Comment: На первый вопрос вы сами себе ответили. На второй тоже - ведь зачем юзеру логиниться заново, если у него уже есть новая пара access + refresh токенов?

Comment: Действительно, видимо не до конца понял, как это всё работает, спасибо